# What would happen when the vitrome-dial hypothalamus get destroyed while there is no food to seek for?

Tags: brain

> Rats with VMH damage overeat because the ventromedial hypothalamus
>   controls the body's ability to digest and store food. (Keesey &
>   Powley, 1975). It controls digestive reflexes. When the ventromedial
>   hypothalamus is damaged, digestive reflexes become overactive and
>   empty the gut abnormally fast. Therefore, the animals start eating
>   sooner than normal and therefore overeat. The rush of extra food
>   cannot be metabolized so it is stored as fat. [The Source](http://indiana.edu/~p1013447/dictionary/hunger_center.htm)

If your ventrome-dial hypothalamus get hit by a hard object somehow or due to infection and is not working properly, more it remains destroyed and unfunctional while there is no food, what will happen?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Just thinking of your hypothesis, how do you suppose the hypothalamus could be struck by a hard object knowing where in the brain it is? Also, how do you suppose an infection could enter the brain considering the blood-brain barrier?